# formatting double precision values in C#

Tags: c#

Say I have a `double` variable initialized as

```
double dValue  = 5.156365
```

I would like to show this in a textbox as 5.16 i.e only two decimal places.

How should I format?

Is `textbox.Text = dValue.ToString("F2", Culture.....)` correct? When I tried it did give me the correct result.  However, if `dValue = 5` then I would like only 5 to be shown and not 5.00.

How could I achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `0` in the string forces that decimal place, while a `#` lets the number get up to that decimal place.

```
   dValue.ToString("0.##")
```